# How can you open a popup window after you close another one?

Tags: javascript, popup, queue

I need to open a popup window, which when closed, opens a new pop up window. Then when you close that one another opens.

I'm aware that this functionality can have uses for spam and nag-ware, but I need it for a user experience survey. <sub>Don't ask me, it wasn't my idea.</sub>

How do you do this?

Comment: Use a when function to do this.

Comment: I don't think this is subjective and argumentative.

Comment: I've said it before and I'll say it again: don't close the question if you can fix it! Closers, what's wrong with the question so amvx can fix it? Too vague, he doesn't propose solutions (just what Joel asks you not to do, just ask the question)... what?

Comment: The title is not clear and the question could have been stated in a better language - but this is in no way subjective. Even the argument that "this question is subjective" is not subjective - it isn't.

Comment: Voting to re-open.  With the edit, I don't see anything subjective and argumentative left.

Comment: I assume the popups on this user experience survey say "Doesn't this bug the crap out of you?", "See, look how obnoxious this is!", "Nope, just a few more clicks, then I'll go away!", "Bye bye!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Popup the first window have an onclose event in the first window that pops-up the second and an onclose event in the second that pops-up first. Have some sort of button on both pages that removes the onclose event so you can escape from it too.

Answer (score 7):

The Javascript in the popup window can access the original window using the `opener` property.

Handle the `onbeforeunload` event in each popup window and call a function in the parent window to continue processing (and open the next window).

For example:

(In the original window)

```
window.onPopupClose = function(popupName) { /* ... */ };
```

(In each popup window)

```
<body onbeforeunload="opener.onPopupClose('someName');}> ... </body>
```

The popupName parameter is just an example, you can do whatever you want (such as having three different functions).

Comment: Fascinating. I always wondered what even Meebo and Gmail use  to ask you stuff when you try to close. onbeforeunload. Great, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<body onbeforeunload="javascript:window.open('Default.aspx','nsf','menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250');">

</body>
```